# How can I prove that this function is bounded using the given hint?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inequality, fractions, absolute-value

How can I prove that this function is bounded using the given hint?
$$f(x) = \frac{1-2\sin x}{1 + \cos^2 x}, $$

**Hint:**

1. $|A + B| \leq |A| + |B|,$
2. $|\sin x| \leq 1.$

Comment: **Hint:** triangle inequality and $1+\cos^2(x)\ge1$

Comment: Third question of this exact form in the last couple of hours. This is not a do-my-homework site. (-1) and voting to close.

Comment: It is not a homework question..... the ideas of the questions are different .@user296602

Comment: @Intuition The ideas of the solutions to the last three problems are identical, if you were to actually spend the time to understand them. Instead, you just ask rapid-fire followups ad nauseum. But hey, you're pretty close to your daily question limit, so I guess that's a self-correcting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1-2\sin{x}}{1+\cos^2x}\leq\frac{|1-2\sin{x}|}{1+\cos^2x}\leq\frac{|1|+|-2\sin{x}|}{1+\cos^2x}\leq\frac{3}{1+\cos^2x}\leq3.$$
$$\frac{1-2\sin{x}}{1+\cos^2x}\geq\frac{|1|-|2\sin{x}|}{1+\cos^2x}\geq\frac{1-2}{1}=-1.$$
Thus, $$-1\leq f(x)\leq3$$ and our function is indeed boubded.